# Changing the default "Free" text on COD checkout page in Prestashop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am using prestashop 1.5.x and i would like to change the word "Free" with "Terms and Condition Apply, Please see next page for details" on this section (see attachment).

[image: How to change the word in circle just for COD]

What would be the simplest way to do it? And which files that are affected ?

I've tried to look at modules/cashondelivery/views/templates/

```
front/payment_execution.tpl
hook/payment.tpl
hook/payment_return.tpl
```

But didn't find anything that might points to that specific text. I think it has something to do with the smarty template as well (CMIIW)

Thank you for your help

Cheers...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texts are located at

```
themes/default/order-carrier.tpl
```

Line 184

```
{l s='Free'}
```

Which means that this text is translatable as Front-Office string.

Easy way to find it is look at compiled HTML for specific classes/ids, for example

```
<div class="delivery_option_price">
```

Then search through all your PrestaShop files for this string and you will find related texts.